# Proving that a polynomial has a positive root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

So I want to prove that a polynomial $ P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n−1}x^{n−1}+.....+a_1x+a_0 $ has a positive root. I'm given that $ a_n $ is positive and $ a_0 $ is negative. I want to know how to apply the intermediate value theorem **EXACTLY**.

Here is what the theorem says:
Let $f$ be a continuous real function on the interval $[a,b]$. If $f(a) \lt f(b)$ and if $c$ is a number such that $f(a) \lt c \lt f(b)$, then there exists a point $x$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(x)=c$.

So I am assuming that polynomials are continuous.  given that $P(0) \lt 0 \lt P(x)$ (for $x$ large enough). So there exists a point $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.

I have some gaps in my understanding of the argument..

Comment: sorry about that,I couldn't figure out how to get the (n-1) as a subscript

Comment: Surround the expression with curly brackets, `{n-1}`.

Comment: Perhaps I am reading too much into the Question, but it seems you have answered it by observing $P(0) = a_0 \lt 0$ and that for $x$ large enough, $P(x) \gt 0$ because $a_n \gt 0$.  Are there some gaps in your understanding those points?  They suffice to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: ok got it thanks

Comment: I think I don't see exactly why they suffice to apply the intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So there exists a point $c$ such that $f(c)=0$." That should be "There exists a point $y\in(0,x)$ such that $f(y)=c$." Afterall $c$ in the range value of $f$, and you want to find an $y$ for $c=0$.

Comment: got it. But why must x be positive?

Comment: @user1961722: I've made an adjustment to be in line with your notation.

Comment: ok that clears everything up,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $a_n \gt 0$ and $a_0 \lt 0$, it must be the case that $n \gt 0$ to avoid an inconsistency.

While it is clear that $P(0) = a_0 \lt 0$, the intuitive notion that $P(x)$ attains positive values for all sufficiently large $x$ deserves a little justification.

What we have to work with is that the leading coefficient $a_n \gt 0$ is positive.  Then for any positive $x \gt 0$ we can write:

$$ P(x) = a_n x^n (1 + b_{n-1}x^{-1} + \ldots + b_0 x^{-n}) $$

where $b_i = a_i/a_n$ for $i = 0,\ldots,n-1$.

Thus the goal of getting $x$ large enough to make $P(x) \gt 0$ can be achieved if and only if:

$$ 1 + b_{n-1}x^{-1} + \ldots + b_0 x^{-n} \gt 0 $$

Equivalently, since $x \gt 0$, what we need to achieve is:

$$ 1 \gt \frac{b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{-1} + \ldots + b_0 x^{-n+1}}{x} $$

$$ x \gt b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{-1} + \ldots + b_0 x^{-n+1} $$

An explicit recipe for $x$ that accomplishes this is to take $B = \max\{ |b_i| : i=0,\ldots,n-1\}$ and choose $x$ that is greater than both $1$ and $nB$.

The first fact, $x \gt 1$, implies the reciprocal powers of $x$ in the expression are each less than $1$.  Thus:

$$ nB \ge |b_{n-1}| + |b_{n-2}| + \ldots + |b_0| \gt b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{-1} + \ldots + b_0 x^{-n+1} $$

Then the second fact, $x \gt nB$, finishes the proof of inequality:

$$ x \gt nB \gt b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{-1} + \ldots + b_0 x^{-n+1} $$

In this way every $x$ which is greater than the maximum of $1$ and $nB$ gives $P(x) \gt 0$.